# Politician says he will vote in favor of legislation that he hasn't read and will change once elected

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

Can anyone come up with a few good synonyms/idioms/expressions for a person or politician that will say whatever he/she believes will get him/her the most votes?

For example:  He/she will vote in favor of a piece of legislation, without having read the legislation and then change the legislation to protect citizen's freedoms after elected.

His/her answers to every political question are answered in such a way (vague) that proponents for both sides of the issue could claim that he/she sided with each proponent?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "typical politician".

Comment: I'm too cynical about politics even to comment.

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's see...

1. A *demagogue* appeals to the "popular" will, and will tend to tell people what s?he thinks they want to hear. Think polling.
2. An *opportunist* will do whatever it takes to advance his/her own position.
3. A *sellout* is bought and paid for by a greater power. In the case of a politician, the power is typically economic. Think lobbies.

Note that #3, in particular, can produce #1 and #2. And #3 has increased drastically in the US over the last 35 years, especially the last 15.

Answer (score 3):

I might call such a person a **vote-catcher.**

See Wordnik's entry for [*vote-catching*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vote-catching) for numerous citations and usage examples.

Answer (score 2):

**Traders in Half-Truths**

> A half-truth is a deceptive statement that includes some element of truth. The statement might be partly true, the statement may be totally true but only part of the whole truth, or it may utilize some deceptive element, such as improper punctuation, or double meaning, especially if the intent is to deceive, evade, blame or misrepresent the truth.
>
> Some forms of half-truths are an inescapable part of politics in representative democracies. The reputation of a political candidate can be irreparably damaged if they are exposed in a lie, so a complex style of language has evolved to minimize the chance of this happening. If someone has not said something, they cannot be accused of lying. As a consequence, politics has become a world where half-truths are expected, and political statements are rarely accepted at face value. see Wikipedia, "half-truths"
>
> "Two half-truths do not make a truth, and two half-cultures do not make a culture."---Arthur Koestler

**Masters of Mendacity**

> Mendacity *noun*: The fact or condition of being untruthful, dishonesty

**Demagogues of Deception**

> Deception, beguilement, deceit, bluff, mystification and subterfuge are acts to propagate beliefs of things that are not true, or not the whole truth (as in half-truths or omission). Deception can involve dissimulation, propaganda, and sleight of hand, as well as distraction, camouflage, or concealment. see Wikipedia, "deception"
>
> Demagogue: one who preaches doctrines he knows to be untrue to men he knows to be idiots.”---H.L. Mencken

**Professional Propagandists**

> Propaganda is a form of communication aimed towards influencing the attitude of a population toward some cause or position.
>
> Propaganda is information that is not impartial and used primarily to influence an audience and further an agenda, often by presenting facts selectively (perhaps lying by omission) to encourage a particular synthesis, or using loaded messages to produce an emotional rather than a rational response to the information presented. see Wikipedia, "propaganda"
>
> "We have made the Reich by propaganda"---Joseph Paul Goebbels, Nazi Politician, 1897-1945
>
> "See, in my line of work you got to keep repeating things over and over and over again for the truth to sink in, to kind of catapult the propaganda."---George W. Bush, 43rd US President

Finally, and as unpalatable as you are likely to find this last offering “**Practical Politicians**” would also be accurate in a representative democracy, such as the US, where most Americans get their picture of reality from the Seven Sisters of Mass Media—-the 7 Transnational Media Corporations--whose evening “*news*” amounts to not much more than a series of “sound-bites”. In such a restricted format complex and nuanced truths are incompatible, and even counter-productive, to a politicians chances of either gaining, or remaining in, public office.

Answer (score 2):

A few positive senses:

> **[Populist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/populist)**
>
> Use the noun populist to describe a person — especially a **[politician](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/populist)**
>   or activist — who works to give regular working people a voice in
>   their government.

Political [**Rhetoric**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rhetoric)-

When people listened eagerly to long speeches, rhetoric was generally used positively; now it is often a negative term, **implying artfulness over real content**.

Comment: ...For every scoundrel there is a hero; that for every selfish politician, there is a dedicated leader..(Abraham Lincoln)

Answer (score 1):

The verb *[pander](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pander)* means

> to do or provide what someone wants or demands even though it is not proper, good, or reasonable *Merriam-Webster*

The noun form *panderer* is often applied to politicians engaged in pandering to the populace.

Answer (score 0):

One evocative term that I have seen used is *weathervane politician*, meaning a politician whose policy positions shift depending on the way the wind blows. A Google Books search finds examples of "weathervane politician" going back to this one from Mark Gruenberg & Arthur Magida, [*Charles H. Percy: Republican Senator From Illinois*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TEcvAAAAYAAJ&q=%22weathervane+politician%22&dq=%22weathervane+politician%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5oblVPaGL4aoogSfgoH4Bw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ) (1973) [combined snippets]:

> In recent years, Pucinski has increasingly become "a stalwart defender of the principle that the man who stays in public office is the man who determines what the majority of his district wants and then follows those wishes explicitly." He has shown a remarkable ability to sense what the popular opinion will be on an issue that has not yet become popular, a talent which caused a veteran Chicago newspaper reporter to almost admiringly call him "the ultimate **weathervane politician**."

Another instance of this term is from Greg Weston, [*Reign of Error: The Inside Story of John Turner's Troubled Leadership*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2FElAAAAMAAJ&q=%22weathervane+politician%22&dq=%22weathervane+politician%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=84jlVJO5O8-MoQTP9ILgCg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBA) (1988) [combined snippets]:

> In Winnipeg he [John Turner] sang hosannas for Pierre Trudeau's efforts on peace and security—a speech drafted from notes prepared for the former prime minister whom Turner so detested. And everywhere he went, Turner spent most of his time slamming Brian Mulroney for making "irresponsible" campaign pledges, for treating voters as "dupes," for having a "hidden agenda" to cut social programs, and finally, for being a **"weathervane" politician**. "Whatever way the public opinion blows, that's Brian, he's with it," he crowed from every stump.

And from Jeff Kingston, [*Contemporary Japan: History, Politics, and Social Change Since the 1980s*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QFocExFkA1MC&pg=PT127&dq=%22weathervane+politician%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=84jlVJO5O8-MoQTP9ILgCg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22weathervane%20politician%22&f=false) (2012):

> While he was premier, [Junichiro] Koizumi was a controversial leader due to his Thatcher-like economic reforms at home, growing security cooperation with the US, and ardent support for George W. Bush's "war ob terror" in the wake of 9/11. These reforms and expanded security cooperation with the US were unpopular, but Koizumi was never a **weathervane politician**. Part of his appeal was his willingness to be bold and decisive, demonstrating leadership qualities that people admired more than his policies and agenda.

Although these three examples emphasize popular opinion as the source of wind, another illustrates that the influence can blow from elsewhere as well. From Paul Ham, [*Hiroshima Nagasaki: The Real Story of the Atomic Bombings*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5FZGAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA262&dq=%22weathervane+politician%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=84jlVJO5O8-MoQTP9ILgCg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22weathervane%20politician%22&f=false) (2014):

> 'Face' and 'feeling' were divergent and often contradictory in the Japanese culture of 1945. What one said bore little relation to how one felt, according to the code of *haragei*, meaning, literally, 'stomach art': 'Our mouths could not speak what our "stomachs" felt', was how Chief Cabinet Secretary [Hisatsune] Sakomizu explained the Japanese practice of 'communicating almost wordlessly by inference and indirection and getting a sense of the meeting by gut feeling and tacit understanding'. The experienced stomach artist felt the truth in his belly, though he dated not utter it; one never laid one's soul on the table (as [Naotake] Sato had brazenly done). To some, Prime Minister [Kantaro] Suzuki seemed a mute, nodding old fool; a **weathervane politician**, who spun with the wishes of the armed forces. To his comrades he was a master of *haragei*.